# Will performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: work with times under 1 sec?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, performselector

Although you can pass sub-second times to performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, it appears that the timer will fire as quickly as it can for any delay under 1 sec. For example, if I set the delay to 100 msec (0.100) or 10 msec (0.010), the timer will still fire in 2 or 3 msec. Is this a known limitation?

For performSelection:withObject:afterDelay:, the documentation for the delay reads:

> delay — The minimum time before which the message is sent. Specifying a delay of 0 does not necessarily cause the selector to be performed immediately. The selector is still queued on the thread’s run loop and performed as soon as possible.

Compare this to NSTimer, where the documentation reads:

> seconds — The number of seconds between firings of the timer. If seconds is less than or equal to 0.0, this method chooses the nonnegative value of 0.1 milliseconds instead.

It appears that performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: uses its delay setting just like NSTimer's seconds setting when a negative value is provided.

Can anyone confirm that that is correct?

Comment: It's not a limitation, it's an implementation detail.  Timers are notoriously inaccurate concepts.  If you need precision, drop down to the kernel level and fire your own notifications.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up, I discovered that `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` was working just fine, and that it wasn't triggering at sub-second intervals because I was passing it an `int` delay as follows:

```
int delay = 0.025; // 25 msec
[self performSelector:@selector(blahBlah:) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
```

OK, my bad! However, this leads to another observation — I thought the compiler would have reported a "loss of precision" when converting a `double` to an `int` without an explicit cast. However, it does not. Beware!

Comment: 6.5 years later, you just saved me a few minutes of screaming into the void about computers being terrible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the delay to 100 msec (0.100) using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, it will NOT be fired in 2 or 3 msec. It will be scheduled on the runloop after 100 msec, and wait until the runloop has the chance to perform. So it may be fired 102 or 103 msec after.